# How to send multiple files and json data with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, form-data

I am trying upload a file with extra data using formData and axios but without luck at all.Basically, the backend expects a `thumb`, `duration`, and `type`. The fields i have named are compulsory when am uploading the file.

I'm using react native expo.Below is the current code that i have.

```
const formatMedia = (medium) => {
  let data = new FormData();
  medium.forEach((media) => {
    data.append('duration');
    data.append('type');
    data.append(
      'thumb',
      {
        uri: media.localUri,
        name: media.filename,
      },
    );
  });
  return data;
};
```

what the backend expects:-

```
[{
  thumb: file,
  duration: number,
  type: string,
}]
```

Comment: If the backend expects `file`, why are you setting `thumbnail`? You want to append a `File` (or `Blob`) but you are appending an object literal with `name` and `uri` properties. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#append_Parameters

Comment: typo in "filename`"

Comment: Backend expects thumb